# Difference between RC4 implementations

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography

I have to implement a RC4 cipher in NodeJS, here is the code:

```
function cipher (CRYPTO, str) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher(CRYPTO.cipherAlgorithm, CRYPTO.password);

  return Buffer.concat([
    cipher.update(str, 'utf-8'),
    cipher.final()
  ]).toString(CRYPTO.encoding);
}

const CRYPTO = {
  cipherAlgorithm: 'rc4',
  password: 'trololol',
  encoding: 'base64'
};

cipher(CRYPTO, '0612345678');
// returns 'yTXp/PZzn+wYsQ=='
```

When i check my implementation with open ssl, i've got the same result:

```
echo -ne "0612345678" |  openssl  rc4 -pass "pass:trololol" -e  -nosalt | base64
> yTXp/PZzn+wYsQ==
```

But with our partner implementation, the result is really different. It is written in Java so i tried to do one and i have the same result than him:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Encryptor {
    private static String algorithm = "RC4";
    public static String encrypt(String key, String value) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec rc4Key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm);
            Cipher rc4 = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

            rc4.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);
            byte [] encrypted = rc4.update(value.getBytes());
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "trololol";
        String value = "0612345678";

        System.out.println(encrypt(key, value));
    }
}
```

Running the above gives:

```
javac Encryptor.java && java Encryptor  
> LYlbWr0URiz+wA==
```

Is it possible that the RC4 algorithm in Java differs from the other ones or is there something wrong in the Java implementation?

Comment: Please really consider not to use RC4, it's [not safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) and also banned in TLS since february 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder but it is our customer choice and despite our warnings we have to deal with this :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is "password" vs "key."

For example with node and OpenSSL, "password" means some value to hash ([using MD5](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bb173f931ae85b464e901806f15dcc219dec6b73/src/node_crypto.cc#L3203-L3210)) to *generate* the key for encryption/decryption.

If you instead use the "password" value as the key (with an empty IV), you will match the value received from Java. For example with node, change to the `createCipheriv()` function:

```
crypto.createCipheriv(CRYPTO.cipherAlgorithm, CRYPTO.password, Buffer.alloc(0));
```